# Array to string conversion PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Any body can help me?
I using MVC.
This is my model code:

```
function activatedNode($node_id){ //to activated selected node
        $data = array (
            'active' => 1
        );
        $this->db-> where ('node_id', "'.$node_id.'"); //here is error line
        $this->db-> update ('node',$data);     
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
function resultRuang(){
    $ruang = $this-> input -> post('ruang');
    $node = $this->search3d -> ambilNodeID($ruang);
    $this->search3d -> nonactivatedNode();
    $this->search3d -> activatedNode($node);
    $data['ruang'] = $this->search3d-> resultRuang ();
    $data['menu_aktif']= 'ruang';
    $data['halaman']= "halaman/resultRuang";
    $this->load->view('template/search_view',$data);
}
```

This is View code:

```
<?php
echo form_open('mainSearch/resultRuang');
echo 'Ruang yang dipilih :';
echo $ruang -> node_id; //this is also error
echo '<a href= "'.base_url().'index.php/mainSearch/searchRuang"> <button name="name"     type="button">Back</button></a>';
echo form_close();
?>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: +1 I don't see a question anywhere.

Comment: Please ask a direct problem, your title gives the nature of the problem but not the actual problem. Please put it in the form of a question or we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, you can do this

```
$this->db->where('node_id', $node_id);
```

And for the second you need to `var_dump($ruang);` and see if `$ruang->node_id` even exists.

Also, showing what errors you get might help.
Read the Stack Overflow FAQ before you post another question.

Comment: $ruang even exist,,

and if

    $this->db-> where ('node_id',$node_id);

will be Database error occured..

Answer (score 0):

In your controller the:

```
    $this->search3d -> activatedNode($node); //incorrect
```

should be

```
    $this->search3d -> activatedNode($node_id);//correct
```

because in your model the function activatedNode($node_id) $node_id doesn't really exist in your function that's why it return false